# How to extract a json from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and in one of the columns there is a string that represents a json:

```
|-----------------------------|
|{"name": "John", "age": "32"}|
|None                         |
|{"name": "Mary", "age": "29"}|
```

I need to create new columns for name and age and extract the data from this json.
Note: It may be null values os missing keys.

Comment: are the quotation marks inside the curly brackets or outside?

Comment: This is not JSON. In JSON, strings must be enclosed in double quotation marks.

Comment: If it's a json like this `'{"name": "John", "age": 32}'` and not above, I gave an answer

Comment: @user2827262 Clearly, you gave an answer to some other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If json strings are like below, try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.DataFrame({'your_column_name':['{"name": "John", "age": 32}', None, '{"name": "Mary", "age": 29}']})
list_of_jsons = df.your_column_name.to_list()
list_of_jsons = [json.loads(s) if s else {"name": None, "name": None} for s in list_of_jsons]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list_of_jsons)
df = pd.concat([df,df2], axis=1)
```

Otherwise what you have in each row is a set with a string in it. You need to parse that string with `str.split()` methods and create your own list of dictionaries (variable I named `list_of_jsons`) and create `df2` and concatenate like above.

Answer (score -1):

Create a couple of new columns named "name" and "age". Apply a function to the column dataframe and parse the content as json with a try/except block. If there is a value, assign it to the name/age columns, if there is no value or the value is null, set the values in the name/age columns to None, accordingly.

Applying a function to a column:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Parse json:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/json